# In R, how can I specify that a generic method takes a ... (dots) argument?

Tags: r, generics, methods

I have a generic method in R:

```
setGeneric(
    "doWork", 
    function(x) { 

        standardGeneric("doWork")
    })

setMethod(
    "doWork", 
    signature = c("character"), 
    definition = function(x) { 

        x
    })
```

How can I add a ... (dots) argument to the definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you can do:

```
setGeneric("doWork", function(x, ...) standardGeneric("doWork"))
setMethod("doWork", signature = c("character"), 
  function(x, ...) do.call(paste, list(x, ..., collapse=" "))
)
```

Then:

```
> doWork("hello", "world", letters[1:5])
[1] "hello world a hello world b hello world c hello world d hello world e"
> doWork(1:3, "world", letters[1:5])
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘doWork’ for signature ‘"integer"’
```

You can even dispatch on `...` if you want under some circumstances.  From `?dotsMethods`:

> Beginning with version 2.8.0 of R, S4 methods can be dispatched (selected and called) corresponding to the special argument “...”. Currently, “...” cannot be mixed with other formal arguments: either the signature of the generic function is “...” only, or it does not contain “...”. (This restriction may be lifted in a future version.)

So if we want a function that only runs if all arguments are "character":

```
setGeneric("doWork2", function(...) standardGeneric("doWork2"))
setMethod("doWork2", signature = c("character"), 
  definition = function(...) do.call(paste, list(..., collapse=" "))
)
doWork2("a", "b", "c")  # [1] "a b c"
doWork2("a", 1, 2)      # Error
```